# how to get index number of array in UItableView

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, indexing

I want to get index's number of UI table Cell and use it as tittel in table cell lable text my output should look like this 
output

> ```
>  Visit #1 
>  Visit #2
>  Visit #3 
>  Visit #4
> ```

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        let cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")! as UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = "visit#\(visits[indexPath.row])"<-- this line 
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: What's not working on your code? Do you get an exception? Do you get a different result than expected?

Comment: all I want to get index number the array visits like in javascript Array indexOf()

Comment: you are looking for `indexPath.row`

Comment: Directly use  `cell.textLabel?.text= "Visit #\(indexPath.row+1)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use indexPath.row like this:

```
cell.textLabel?.text= "Visit #\(indexPath.row + 1)"
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of `indexPath.row` is directly the index's number of the table view cell.

Writing `cell.textLabel?.text = "visit#\(indexPath.row)"` should give you the expected result.